# Spring Webflux and Testcontainers - Database container launched via R2DBC URL scheme error

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, testcontainers, r2dbc

I'm trying to write some database integration tests in my first Spring Webflux application. I liked the idea behind @Testcontainers and I'm attempting to launch a Postgresql container instead of going the H2 route. I'm going by the official documentation here : https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/r2dbc/

I've tried to set this up in two ways, using a tc profile and creating the container programmatically. Both give me the same nested error:

```
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 127.0.0.1:2375
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2974)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3145)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChar(URI.java:3155)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3170)
    at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:623)
    at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:904)
    ... 81 more
```

So that's not a complete URL but I was expecting testcontainers to handle the url based on the schema below.

application-tc.properties

```
spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:tc:postgresql:///mydb?TC_IMAGE_TAG=14.4-alpine
```

Test class

```
package com.rxjava.babybank.repository;

import com.rxjava.babybank.model.Account;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.data.r2dbc.DataR2dbcTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import java.util.List;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataR2dbcTest
@Testcontainers
@ActiveProfiles("tc")
public class AccountRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    AccountRepository repository;

//    private static PostgreSQLContainer<BabyPostgresqlContainer> container = BabyPostgresqlContainer.getInstance();
//
//    @DynamicPropertySource
//    public static void overrideProps(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
//        registry.add("spring.r2dbc.url", () -> "r2dbc:postgresql://"
//                + container.getHost() + ":" + container.getFirstMappedPort()
//                + "/" + container.getDatabaseName());
//        registry.add("spring.r2dbc.username", container::getUsername);
//        registry.add("spring.r2dbc.password", container::getPassword);
//    }

    @AfterEach
    public void emptyRepository() {
        repository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldBeEmpty() {
        repository.findAll().as(StepVerifier::create).expectNextCount(0).verifyComplete();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldGetInsertedValues() {
        Account acc1 = new Account("acc1", "cust1", 2000L, "RON");
        Account acc2 = new Account("acc2", "cust2", 200000L, "EUR");
        Account acc3 = new Account("acc3", "cust1", 3000L, "EUR");

        repository.saveAll(List.of(acc1, acc2, acc3));

        repository.findAll().as(StepVerifier::create).expectNextCount(3).verifyComplete();
    }
}
```

BabyPostgresqlContainer

```
package com.rxjava.babybank.integration;

import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;

public class BabyPostgresqlContainer extends PostgreSQLContainer<BabyPostgresqlContainer> {
    private static final String IMAGE_VERSION = "postgres:14.4-alpine";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb";
    private static BabyPostgresqlContainer container;

    private BabyPostgresqlContainer() {
        super(IMAGE_VERSION);
    }

    public static BabyPostgresqlContainer getInstance() {
        if (container == null) {
            container = new BabyPostgresqlContainer().withDatabaseName(DATABASE_NAME);
        }
        return container;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        System.setProperty("DB_URL", container.getJdbcUrl());
        System.setProperty("DB_USERNAME", container.getUsername());
        System.setProperty("DB_PASSWORD", container.getPassword());
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        //do nothing, JVM handles shut down
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I know those aren't useful unit tests, just trying to figure out how to write them using the default @R2dbcRepository methods.

PPS: Full error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectNextCount(3)" failed (expected: count = 3; actual: counted = 0; signal: onError(org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to obtain R2DBC Connection; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy: Provider org.testcontainers.dockerclient.EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy could not be instantiated))

    at reactor.test.MessageFormatter.assertionError(MessageFormatter.java:115)
    at reactor.test.MessageFormatter.failPrefix(MessageFormatter.java:104)
    at reactor.test.MessageFormatter.fail(MessageFormatter.java:73)
    at reactor.test.MessageFormatter.failOptional(MessageFormatter.java:88)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.checkCountMismatch(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1372)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onSignalCount(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1609)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onExpectation(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1466)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onError(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.deferredError(FluxUsingWhen.java:398)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$RollbackInner.onComplete(FluxUsingWhen.java:475)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4397)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.onError(FluxUsingWhen.java:364)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:842)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:608)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:588)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(FluxFlatMap.java:451)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxError.subscribe(FluxError.java:43)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8466)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$ResourceSubscriber.onError(FluxUsingWhen.java:220)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:134)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4397)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetry$RetrySubscriber.onError(FluxRetry.java:95)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:172)
    at reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.fail(AbstractPool.java:475)
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.lambda$drainLoop$9(SimpleDequePool.java:431)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(FluxDoOnEach.java:186)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93)
    at org.testcontainers.r2dbc.ConnectionPublisher$StateMachineSubscription$WaitFutureCompletionSubscriptionState.lambda$enter$0(ConnectionPublisher.java:86)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenCompleteStage(CompletableFuture.java:887)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:2325)
    at org.testcontainers.r2dbc.ConnectionPublisher$StateMachineSubscription$WaitFutureCompletionSubscriptionState.enter(ConnectionPublisher.java:83)
    at org.testcontainers.r2dbc.ConnectionPublisher$StateMachineSubscription.transitionTo(ConnectionPublisher.java:55)
    at org.testcontainers.r2dbc.ConnectionPublisher$StateMachineSubscription$WaitRequestSubscriptionState.request(ConnectionPublisher.java:67)
    at org.testcontainers.r2dbc.ConnectionPublisher$StateMachineSubscription.request(ConnectionPublisher.java:45)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.request(FluxDoOnEach.java:108)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.request(FluxContextWrite.java:136)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2194)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxOnErrorResume.java:74)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxContextWrite.java:101)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxDoOnEach.java:121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:70)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:70)
    at org.testcontainers.r2dbc.ConnectionPublisher.subscribe(ConnectionPublisher.java:29)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFromPublisher.subscribe(MonoFromPublisher.java:63)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4397)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatArray.java:258)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray.subscribe(FluxConcatArray.java:78)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8466)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribeWith(Flux.java:8639)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8436)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8360)
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.drainLoop(SimpleDequePool.java:453)
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.pendingOffer(SimpleDequePool.java:600)
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.doAcquire(SimpleDequePool.java:296)
    at reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.request(AbstractPool.java:430)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:110)
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool$QueueBorrowerMono.subscribe(SimpleDequePool.java:720)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetry$RetrySubscriber.resubscribe(FluxRetry.java:117)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRetry.subscribeOrReturn(MonoRetry.java:50)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4382)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:172)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:134)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4397)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen.subscribe(FluxUsingWhen.java:104)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8466)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen.subscribe(FluxUsingWhen.java:94)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8466)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.toVerifierAndSubscribe(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:891)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:831)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:823)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.verifyComplete(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:690)
    at com.rxjava.babybank.repository.AccountRepositoryTest.shouldGetInsertedValues(AccountRepositoryTest.java:54)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
    Suppressed: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to obtain R2DBC Connection; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy: Provider org.testcontainers.dockerclient.EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy could not be instantiated
        at org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.lambda$getConnection$0(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:88)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorMap$31(Mono.java:3730)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94)
        ... 95 more
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy: Provider org.testcontainers.dockerclient.EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy could not be instantiated
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:315)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:320)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1770)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy: Provider org.testcontainers.dockerclient.EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy could not be instantiated
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:586)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:813)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:729)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1403)
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:74)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.getOrInitializeStrategy(DockerClientFactory.java:133)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:176)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory$1.getDockerClient(DockerClientFactory.java:90)
        at com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClientDelegate.authConfig(DockerClientDelegate.java:108)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:325)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLR2DBCDatabaseContainer.start(PostgreSQLR2DBCDatabaseContainer.java:12)
        at org.testcontainers.r2dbc.TestcontainersR2DBCConnectionFactory.lambda$null$3(TestcontainersR2DBCConnectionFactory.java:54)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 127.0.0.1:2375
        at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:906)
        at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultDockerClientConfig$Builder.withDockerHost(DefaultDockerClientConfig.java:360)
        at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultDockerClientConfig$Builder.withProperties(DefaultDockerClientConfig.java:342)
        at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultDockerClientConfig.createDefaultConfigBuilder(DefaultDockerClientConfig.java:221)
        at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultDockerClientConfig.createDefaultConfigBuilder(DefaultDockerClientConfig.java:210)
        at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy.<init>(EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy.java:34)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:789)
        ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 127.0.0.1:2375
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2974)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3145)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChar(URI.java:3155)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3170)
        at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:623)
        at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:904)
        ... 25 more
```

Comment: Looking at the stacktrace, it's not about your code or the JDBC connection string, but rather the Testcontainers library failed to connect to your local docker installation. Did you customize any Testcontainers settings? Which operation system do you use? You can also check this link https://www.testcontainers.org/features/configuration/#customizing-docker-host-detection

Comment: It appears you're right. I had DOCKER_HOST set as 127.0.0.1:2375 in my Environment Variables. I'm in IntelliJ on Windows. I'm now trying to use testcontainers.properties to set docker properties but I'm probably doing it wrong since I'm now getting: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration

Comment: I can only recommend this page: https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/windows/, because I don't have any personal experience with Testcontainers on Windows. Good luck.

Comment: Are you using Docker Desktop on Windows? This should work out of the box, so please remove the further configuration. Feel free to drop into our Slack, so we can look at it together: https://slack.testcontainers.org/

Comment: @KevinWittek I'm actually not using Docker Desktop. I'm running dockerd in wsl2. I also stumbled upon this https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/4958 Does this mean that what I'm trying to do is a no-go? I can't use Docker Desktop

Comment: It is not a no-go, it is just simply not supported automatically, since this is quite an advanced setup, if you want to use the Docker daemon inside WSL from within a Windows process (if you use it with a Linux process, it will work automatically OOTB).

As you can find in the issue you linked, there are different examples of working configurations.